# expires the next day at 06:00 a.m

Tags: nginx, cache-control

Currently I use this nginx config to cache `index.html` for one day:

```
location /index.html {
  gzip_static on;
  expires 1d;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
  break;
}
```

Is there a way to configure that the cache always expires the next day at 06:00 a.m.?

Comment: Have you tried `exipres @6h30m;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires

> In addition, it is possible to specify a time of the day using the “@” prefix (0.7.9, 0.6.34):
>
> ```
>    expires @15h30m;
> ```